# Up key for XTerm, Korn shell (while vt100 through telnet/putty works) dont work

Tags: xterm, ksh

I am using xterm on korn shell. I have defined in .kshrc as follows:

```
set -o emacs

alias __A=`echo "\020"`     # up arrow = ^p = back a command

alias __B=`echo "\016"`     # down arrow = ^n = down a command

alias __C=`echo "\006"`     # right arrow = ^f = forward a character

alias __D=`echo "\002"`     # left arrow = ^b = back a character

alias __H=`echo "\001"`     # home = ^a = start of line

alias __Y=`echo "\005"`     # end = ^e = end of line
```

I do a source ./.kshrc (in my home), but the up key press is doing nothing. Same action in bash displays older executed commands.

Also, in korn shell, history command dont show history (when in xterm), shows following msg - /bin/ksh: hist: 1-0: invalid range.

Answer (score 0):

If the emacs bindings do not work, use the vi bindings instead. Replace `set -o emacs` with `set -o vi` in your `.kshrc`, then add the following to your `.vimrc` file:

```
set cpo-=<
nmap k <Up>
nmap j <Down>
nmap h <Left>
nmap l <Right>
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for the `/bin/ksh: hist: 1-0: invalid range` solution here: For me it turned out, that `HISTFILE` was set to `/dev/null` somewhere globally.

Adding `export HISTFILE="${HOME}/.sh_history"` to my `~/.kshrc` solved it.